# Obtener el total de incidencias ordenadas por numero de empleado mysql

Tags: mysql

Buenas necesito traer una consulta que me devuelva todas las incidencias de tipo U ordenadas por empleado que mas tenga de arriba a abajo.

Seria esta consulta ordenada por el empleado que mas tenga de arriba a abajo

```
Select * from 'historial' where tipo = 'u' order by empleado
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado algo así sin resultados:

```
SELECT * FROM `historial` WHERE TIPO = 'u' ORDER BY max(COUNT(empleado))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes que hacer el `COUNT` de cada empleado y agrupar (con `GROUP BY`) los resultados por cada uno de ellos. Luego lo ordenas de forma ascendente (`ASC`) o descendente (`DESC`)

```
SELECT empleado, COUNT(*) as cuantos
FROM `historial` 
WHERE TIPO = 'u' 
GROUP BY empleado
ORDER BY cuantos DESC
```

Si lo que quieres es la lista de usuarios y sus incidencias, pero que aparezcan primero los que más incidencias tienen puedes hacer un `JOIN` con la consulta mencionada.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `historial` a
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT empleado, COUNT(*) as cuantos
   FROM `historial` 
   WHERE TIPO = 'u' 
   GROUP BY empleado
) b on a.empleado = b.empleado
ORDER BY cuantos DESC
```

Comment: Y habría alguna manera de ordenar la consulta entera que he mostrado arriba mostrando los primeros resultados el empleado que mas tenga y así sucesivamente? Gracias.

Comment: Con el `ORDER BY cuantos DESC` la ordenación queda como tu dices, aparecen primero los que tienen más incidencias.

Comment: Quiero decir obtener el mismo resultado que en la captura pero ordenado por ejemplo las filas que aparecen con usuario Richard (del que mas ahi) que aparezcan las primeras, no un contador, no se si me explico

Comment: He editado la respuesta añadiendo una consulta, a ver si se ajusta a lo que buscas.

Comment: No es exactamente lo que buscaba pero me ha ayudado, gracias!